# Is It possible to change dynamically delay on a Scheduled Poller in Camel via JMX?

Tags: jmx, apache-camel

I would like to set/change the delay of a File consumer at runtime through JMX.
I am able to change the value of the property but it doesn't seem to be taken into account until I restart the consumer.

Example with the camel-archetype-java and its basic file example:

- Run It
- Change the delay of the File Consumer by calling the setDelay Operation with the JConsole
- Delay property of the Consumer is changed but logs show it continues to poll at 500ms by default
- Stop/Start the consumer
- New value of delay is used by the consumer

Do I need anothers steps or active any configuration to make it work at runtime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the value on the file endpoint, and then restart the route, eg stop route, start route.

Comment: So the value is only loaded at the consumer initialisation. Since restarting the consumer is not a big deal, I'm gonna go this way. Thanks !

Comment: Yeah, well a scheduled thread pool is used under the covers to trigger when to poll for files. The thread pool is exposed in JMX as well. I am not sure if it allows to configure its trigger delay on the fly with JMX.